# "Login failed for user '<user>'." when using DefaultConnection in MVC 5 on SQL Azure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm publishing a web application to Azure, which has two database connection strings.

```
    <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Server=tcp:myserver.database.windows.net,1433;Database=mydb;User ID=myuser@myserver;Password=mypassword;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
    <add name="MyApp" connectionString="Server=tcp:myserver.database.windows.net,1433;Database=mydb;User ID=myuser@myserver;Password=mypassword;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

The `MyApp` database connection is working. Entity Framework uses this to provide the site functionality. Therefore, this connection string is valid.

However, the `DefaultConnection` database connection does not work when running on the Azure platform, which is used by the ASP.NET MVC Membership/Authorization API. This code is boiler-plate/scaffold with very minimal modification. I just copied the working connection string for `MyApp` and named it `DefaultConnection`. I know that it is this `DefaultConnection` because the error occurs when I am trying to log in, which is the first time it would use that connection string.

When running on Azure, I get the error:

> Login failed for user 'myuser'. This session has been assigned a
>   tracing ID of 'dad6972c-2b65-4441-b09b-7994de11a47d'.  Provide this
>   tracing ID to customer support when you need assistance.

To clarify, the `DefaultConnection` works fine locally, *but not when published to Azure*. Here are my tests:

- The identical connections work fine running locally using my locally hosted database/server.
- The identical connections work fine running locally but accessing the SQL Azure database. So the user is "good".
- The username/password is correct, as soon as I change them when running the above scenario, I get the error mentioned
- I've copied/pasted the connection strings from the Azure portal with no difference (obviously changing my password placeholders)
- *but* when I deploy the application accessing the SQL Azure database (known to work locally) and execute the code on Azure Web Apps, it fails with the error mentioned.
- I've ruled out transformation errors by checking the transforms and also just removing the transformation logic entirely and "hardcoding" the connection strings, so the publishing logic is not interfering.

I'm at a total loss. I've tried modifying the options on the connection string, eg. trusting certificates, etc., but with no luck. If I can connect locally but to the remote SQL Azure database, why not when running on Azure itself?

Comment: There will be a "Connection Strings" section under the Configuration settings for Azure website check the credentials there is correct..i had gone through this once..that time the password there is wrong eventhough the password at webconfig is correct

Comment: Yes, that was it. Had to be something daft like that. Thanks very much. You should answer the question so I can give you the credit proper.

Comment: glad it worked :) will put it as answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There will be a `Connection Strings` section under the Configuration settings for Azure website check the credentials there is correct.i had gone through this once..that time the password there is wrong even though the password at web-config file is correct